# adding events into database from primefaces schedule

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am very new to jsf primefaces and all. I have created a schedule calendar using the primefaces schedule, used the same code as given in the showcase. What I now want is how to add the event i create the calendar to database. I have created an entity for the event which contains the event_descripion and date. How should I bind the Event entity with the event I create in the schedule calendar?

I really hope someone will help me. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately, you have to deal with this yourself. Primefaces component just add the event to the calendar model, which remains in memory, in the managed bean scope.

```
private ScheduleModel eventModel;
```

it's up to you to persist these events into a database and then retrieve them later.

Comment: How to persist these events into the database?

Comment: Well that is not exactly what I asked. In the xhtml file I have "bean.event.title" or "bean.event.startDate". If I put "bean.title" and "bean.startDate" I am able to save the values into the database. Is there any other way to do it? Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: Is the bean event serializable?

Comment: What I understood from the primefaces schedule showcase is event is an object of ScheduleEvent (which is an interface).

Comment: in the showcase, the events being added are DefaultScheduleEvent (see the controller initialization at http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/schedule.jsf) and it implements serializable (http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.4/org/primefaces/model/DefaultScheduleEvent.html) so you have IMO 3 ways here: [1] serialize it using ObjectOutputStream or [2] introspecting the object and serializing as JSON or XML or CSV or [3] choosing the relevant attributes and storing them into a database (as you've suggested - I like this option) or into a file.

Comment: notice that primefaces is a presentation layer library, so it does not care how you're going to persist the data. It provides support on the backing bean level. The persistence option you're going to use to primefaces components is a decision left to you

Comment: Thank you Leo. I was able to do that now. :) Thanks a lot :)

Comment: thank you. and don't forget to mark the answer, if you think it solved your problem. good day